# How to stop having a white square when using a sprite vector with SFML 2?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make a sprite vector but the first few elements always show a white square.
The variables are contained in the TileRPG class to then be used in the main.cpp
tile.cpp

```
void TileRPG::draw(int id, float x, float y, sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    m_sprite[id].setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x, y));
    window.draw(m_sprite[id]);
}


TileRPG::TileRPG() {
    std::ifstream file { "data/tileRPGList.rf" };
    std::string line{ "" }, access { "" };
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        m_texture.push_back(texture);
        m_sprite.push_back(sprite);
        access = "data/" + line;
        m_texture[i].loadFromFile(access);
        m_sprite[i].setTexture(m_texture[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

tile.hpp

```
class Tile {
protected:
    std::vector<sf::Texture> m_texture;
    std::vector<sf::Sprite> m_sprite;
};

class TileRPG : public Tile {
public:
    TileRPG();
    void draw(int id, float x, float y, sf::RenderWindow& window);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The problem

From the [`sf::Sprite::setTexture()` documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560):

> the sprite doesn't store its own copy of the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function.

So, an `sf::Sprite` object doesn't store a copy of an `sf::Texture` object. By the way, this is related to [The Flyweight Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern), as it can be inferred from [`sf::Sprite`'s documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#details):

> The separation of `sf::Sprite` and `sf::Texture` allows more flexibility and better performances: indeed a `sf::Texture` is a heavy resource, and any operation on it is slow (often too slow for real-time applications). On the other side, a `sf::Sprite` is a lightweight object which can use the pixel data of a `sf::Texture` and draw it with its own transformation/color/blending attributes.

The `m_texture` data member in your code is a vector of `sf::Texture` objects, i.e., **`std::vector<sf::Texture>`**. Calling `push_back()` on it will reallocate the vector's internal buffer if it doesn't have enough capacity to store the `sf::Texture` object to insert. Therefore, the `sf::Texture` objects stored in an `std::vector<sf::Texture>` may end up being located in a different position in memory after calling `push_back()`. Since the `sf::Sprite` objects just keep pointers to `sf::Texture` objects, these pointers will end up pointing to the wrong location in memory if the `sf::Texture` objects have been reallocated somewhere else in memory.

#### Possible Solutions

You could simply call `std::vector::reserve()` to **reserve enough memory upfront** for the vector's internal buffer. The drawback to this approach is that you would ideally need to know in advance the number of `sf::Texture` objects your vector is going to store to avoid wasting memory.

Another approach would be to call `sf::Sprite::setTexture()` only **after** you have properly populated the `std::vector<sf::Texture>` container. This way, as you aren't going to further insert `sf::Texture` objects into the vector, it won't reallocate its internal buffer.

Lastly, an alternative approach regarding container would be to define `m_texture` as an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>>` instead. This way, if a reallocation of the vector's internal buffer happens, only the address of the `std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>` objects are affected, **not** the addresses of the *pointee* objects, (i.e., not the addresses of the `sf::Texture` objects). You could also use [`boost::stable_vector`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/container/stable_vector.html) for the same purpose. In this case, you would just define `m_texture` as `boost::stable_vector<sf::Texture>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`Sprite::setTexture` doesn't make a copy of the texture, but stores a pointer to it. This pointer is then invalidated once the vector of textures reallocates its storage in one of the subsequent `push_back`s.